# Precedence, HTML and PHP Index File

Tags: apache

I put an index.html file and an index.php file in the root directory of my site together, when I navigate to my site, www.site.com, it serves the php file instead of the html file, my question is why? Why does it serve the php over html? Apache server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the DirectoryIndex directive of Apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

For instance

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Will try to serve first the html, if it doesn't exist it will serve the php.

Answer (score 1):

Apache can be told to prefer the .php or the .html file.

Look for a section like this in the configuration file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

and change it to

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```